# Why is my app icon not showing on my actual phone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I know that there are other questions but their solution didn't work for me. I've added all pngs images for each iDevice in the AppIcon, in Assets folder. The icon is appearing in the simulators, but not on my actual iPhone, as well on my brother's iPhone.

I've already rebooted my iPhone, deleted the app, cleaned the project, deleted the cache folder of the project, I've done everything that I found in here, but none of them worked.

Yes, the icons are in the correct size for each iPhone, it's in PNG format, it's all ok. I've set the "Asset catalog app icon set name" to the AppIcon catalog, where all my icons are.

If it's helpful, when I've archived the app in the past, the icon was not there either. It only appears in the simulator. Would you please help me?

Comment: Add icons entry in info.plist too and try again.

Comment: Are all icons in the right image asset? Is the image asset selected in the general tab of the target? Are all icons the right size?

Comment: That was the problem, the size... Fixed now!

Answer (score 3):

Check the icon images you have created are of the correct dimensions given?

here is a link on which you can create all icon images for ios as well as android.

http://makeappicon.com/

hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

make sure your pointing to the correct app icons source, in your project settings and clean the project settings, product >> clean  (hold alt to clean build folder as well) [project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec7sj.png)